# Unable to validate access credentials when creating/using presigned URLs in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm using boto3 to copy encrypted EBS snapshots from one region to another, but I've been getting `Invalid presigned URL` messages when I try to copy. I'm generating the presigned URL using the boto3 client method `generate_presigned_url` in the source region and calling the copy function in the destination region like so:

```
uw2_client = non_prod.client(
    'ec2', 
    region_name="us-west-2", 
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
presigned_url = uw2_client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='copy_snapshot',
    Params={
        'SourceSnapshotId': og_snapshot_id,   # Original snapshot ID
        'SourceRegion': 'us-west-2',
        'DestinationRegion': 'us-east-1'
        # I also tried include all parameters from copy_snapshot.
        # It didn't make a difference.
        # 'Description': desc,
        # 'KmsKeyId': 'alias/xva-nonprod-all-amicopykey',
        # 'Encrypted': True,
    }
)
```

Here's my code to create the copy.

```
ue1_client = non_prod.client(
    'ec2', 
    region_name="us-east-1", 
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
response = ue1_client.copy_snapshot(
    Description=desc,
    KmsKeyId='alias/xva-nonprod-all-amicopykey',   # Exists in us-east-1
    Encrypted=True,
    SourceSnapshotId=og_snapshot_id,
    SourceRegion='us-west-2',
    DestinationRegion='us-east-1',
    PresignedUrl=pre_signed_url
)
```

It successfully returns the presigned URL. But if I attempt to use that presigned URL to copy a snapshot, I get the invalid URL error. If I try to validate the url:

```
r = requests.post(presigned_url)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

I get:

```
<Response>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Code>AuthFailure</Code>
            <Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
    <RequestID>3189bb5b-54c9-4d11-ab4c-762cbea32d9a</RequestID>
</Response>
```

You'd think that it would an issue with my credentials, but I'm not sure how... It's the same credentials I'm using to create the pre-signed URL. And my IAM user has unfettered access to EC2.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but I cannot figure out what it is. Any insight would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Just to confirm that it's not a permissions issue, I tried this with my personal account which has access to everything. Still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the documentation is wrong... A signed URL is NOT required when copying encrypted snapshots within the same account (according to AWS Support).

From AWS Support:

> ... it's not actually necessary to create the pre-signed URL in order to copy encrypted snapshot from one region to another (within the same AWS account).

However, according to their documentation, it's not possible to copy encrypted snapshots to another account either...   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The current [boto3.EC2.Client.copy_snapshot](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.copy_snapshot) function documentation says:

> **PresignedUrl (string) --**
>
> When you copy an encrypted source snapshot using the Amazon EC2 Query API, you must supply a pre-signed URL. This parameter is optional for unencrypted snapshots.

Instead, it can simply be accomplished by creating the client object in the destination region and calling the `copy_snapshot()` method like so:

```
try:
    ec2 = boto3.client(
        service_name='ec2',
        region_name='us-east-1'
    )

    ec2.copy_snapshot(
        SourceSnapshotId='snap-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        SourceRegion='us-west-2',
        Encrypted=True,
        KmsKeyId='DestinationRegionKeyId'
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```